# Replicate inherance structure in Cython wrapper classes

Tags: inheritance, cython

Let's say I have the following C++ code defined i `AB.h`:

```
class A {
public:
    void foo() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void bar() {}
};
```

I want to wrap shared pointers to objects of these classes in Cython so I make the following `pxd` file:

```
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr

cdef extern from "AB.h":
    cdef cppclass A:
        void foo()
    cdef cppclass B:
        void bar()

cdef class APy:
    cdef shared_ptr[A] c_self

cdef class BPy(APy): 
    cdef shared_ptr[B] c_self # <-- Error compiling Cython file: 'c_self' redeclared
```

And the following `pyx` file:

```
cdef class APy:
    def foo(self):
        return self.c_self.get().foo()

cdef class BPy(APy):
    def bar(self):
        return self.c_self.get().bar()
```

As you can see this does not compile. My goal is to have BPy inherit the `foo` python function from `APy` so that I don't have to write it twice. I can skip `BPy(APy)`, and just write `BPy`, but then I have to write

```
def foo(self):
    return self.c_self.get().foo()
```

in the definition of `BPy` as well.

I can rename `c_self` in `BPy` to something else (e.g `c_b_self`) and then assign my pointer to both `c_self` and `c_b_self` when creating objects of `BPy`, but is there a more elegant way of achieving my goal?

Comment: You may gain some insights from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573479/cython-python-c-inheritance-passing-derived-class-as-argument-to-function-e . As @chrisb points out, to wrap complicated c++ structures, pybind11 may be an easier way. But it hides too many details. To use it well,  a good understanding of c++ semantics and some tricky template techniques requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surprisingly, that despite feeling naturally, there is no straight forward way to make `PyB` a subclass of `PyA`, - after all `B` is a subclass of `A`!

However, the desired hierarchy violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56860/5769463) in some subtle ways. This principle says something along the lines:

> If `B` is a subclass of `A`, then the objects of type `A` can be
>   replaced by objects of type `B` without breaking the semantics of
>   program.

It is not directly obvious, because the public interfaces of `PyA` and `PyB` are ok from Liskov's point of view, but there is one (implicit) property which makes our life harder:

- `PyA` can wrap any object of type `A`
- `PyB` can wrap any object of type `B`, also can do **less** than `PyB`!

This observation means there will be no beautiful solution for the problem, and your proposal of using different pointers isn't that bad.

My solution presented bellow has a very similar idea, only that I use a cast rather  (which might improve the performance slightly by paying some type-safety), than to cache the pointer.

To make the example stand-alone I use inline-C-verbatim code and to make it more general I use classes without nullable constructors:

```
%%cython --cplus

cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <iostream>
    class A {
    protected:
        int number;    
    public:
        A(int n):number(n){}
        void foo() {std::cout<<"foo "<<number<<std::endl;}
    };

    class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int n):A(n){}
        void bar() {std::cout<<"bar "<<number<<std::endl;}
    };
    """   
    cdef cppclass A:
        A(int n)
        void foo()
    cdef cppclass B(A): # make clear to Cython, that B inherits from A!
        B(int n)
        void bar()
 ...
```

Differences to your example:

1. constructors have a parameter and thus aren't nullable
2. I let the Cython know, that `B` is a subclass of `A`, i.e. use `cdef cppclass B(A)` - thus we can omit castings from `B` to `A` later on.

Here is the wrapper for class `A`:

```
...
cdef class PyA:
    cdef A* thisptr  # ptr in order to allow for classes without nullable constructors

    cdef void init_ptr(self, A* ptr):
        self.thisptr=ptr

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.init_ptr(new A(n))

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if NULL != self.thisptr:
            del self.thisptr

    def foo(self):
        self.thisptr.foo()
...
```

Noteworthy details are:

- `thisptr` is of type `A *` and not `A`, because `A` has no nullable constructor
- I use raw-pointer (thus `__dealloc__` needed) for holding the reference, maybe one could considered using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, depending on how the class is used.
- When an object of class `A` is created, `thisptr` is automatically initialized to `nullptr`, so there is no need to explicitly set `thisptr` to `nullptr` in `__cinit__` (which is the reason `__cinit__` is omitted).
- Why `__init__` and not `__cinit__` is used will become evident in a little while.

And now the wrapper for class `B`:

```
...
cdef class PyB(PyA):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.init_ptr(new B(n))

    cdef B* as_B(self):
        return <B*>(self.thisptr)  # I know for sure it is of type B*!

    def bar(self):
        self.as_B().bar()
```

Noteworthy details:

- `as_B` is used to cast `thisptr` to `B` (which it really is) instead of keeping an cached `B *`-pointer.
- There is a subtle difference between `__cinit__` and `__init__`: `__cinit__` of the parent class will be always called, yet the `__init__` of the parent class will only be called, when there is no implementation of the `__init__`-method for the class itself.  Thus, we use `__init__` because we would like to override/omit setting of `self.thisptr` of the basis-class.

And now (it prints to std::out and not the ipython-cell!):

```
>>> PyB(42).foo()
foo 42  
>>> PyB(42).bar()
bar 42
```

---

One last thought: I did the experience, that using inheritance in order to "save code" often led to problems, because one ended up with "wrong" hierarchies for wrong reasons. There might be another tools to reduce boilerplate code (like pybind11-framework mentioned by @chrisb) that are better for this job.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question (would be curious if there is one!) - but one option would be to wrap with [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) - it can handle this without too much hassle.

#### wrapper.cpp

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

#include "AB.h"    

namespace py = pybind11;    
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    py::class_<A>(m, "A")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("foo", &A::foo);

    py::class_<B, A>(m, "B") // second template param is parent
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("bar", &B::bar);
}
```

#### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import pybind11

setup(ext_modules=[Extension('example', ['wrapper.cpp'], 
                             include_dirs=[pybind11.get_include()])])
```